# In a electric circuit, while applying Kirchhoff's law, why the current ($i$) is governed by the $2^\text{nd}$ order derivative

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, differentiation

If I get the equation $\frac{d^2i}{dt^2} + 44i = 23 \cos5t$ after applying Kirchhoff's law, the current $i$ is governed by the second-order differential equation. What is its meaning?

[image]

Comment: How did you arrive at this differential equation? What kind of electronic circuit do you have? (May be it is an LC-circuit driven by an external voltage. But we should not guess.) 
Please provide a drawing of your circuit.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch is is lc circuit

Comment: In the given circuit, the voltage from the power supply equals then sum of the other two: q/C + L{$d^2$q/d$t^2$).  Where did you get your equation?

Comment: The equation does not seem to match the circuit. For one thing, if 44i is a voltage drop, the implication is there is a resistor of magnitude 44 in series with the capacitor and inductor.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the *first* derivative as a rate of change. So $\frac{di}{dt}$ tells you how fast is $i$ changing with respect to time.

For the *second* derivative applying the same idea, $\frac{d^2 i}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \left[\frac{di}{dt}\right]$ tells you how fast $\frac{di}{dt}$ is changing with respect to time.

Since $\frac{di}{dt}$ is itself a rate of change, $\frac{d^2 i}{dt}$ tells you if that change in current is increasing or decreasing. It is often intuitive to think of $\frac{di}{dt}$ as something analogous to mechanical velocity and $\frac{d^2 i}{dt}$ as mechanical acceleration.

So you may say that your equation is establishing a relation between the current $i$ and its own "acceleration".